# paypal changing from sandbox to live

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I have created my site and got all working with the sandbox, I have turned the app to live and changed the tokens.  I am getting the following error message and I can see the http header is referencing the sandbox  I have changed this in PHP SDK ini file and set the mode to live

error

Got Http response code 401 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token

ini file

```
 mode=live
 ;Service Configuration
 [Service]
 ;service.EndPoint="https://api.sandbox.paypal.com"
 ; Uncomment this line for integrating with the live endpoint 
 service.EndPoint="https://api.paypal.com"
```

how else can I set the correct https header?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove all `sandbox` from all the links.
for example, this link `https://api.sandbox.paypal.com` would become `https://api.paypal.com`